# Variable not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

Sorry if this is very basic question. I'm a Java guy and new to CPP. As per logic everything looks fine to me. But the compiler still throwing the error

"**result** was not declared in this scope " What might be the reason ?

And line causing error is

```
  ns1__changePinTestResponse* result= soap_new_ns1__ChangePinResponse(this);
```

Here are my codes.

```
int ATLServerService::changePinTest(_ns1__changePinTest *ns1__changePinTest, _ns1__changePinTestResponse *ns1__changePinTestResponse)
{
    LOG_DEBUG_MSG("ATLServerService::changePassword()");
    char* accountID = (char*)ns1__changePinTest->accountID.c_str();
    int accountPin = ns1__changePinTest->accountPin;
    char* newPassword = (char*)ns1__changePinTest->newPassword.c_str();
    char* yourSerialNumber = (char*)ns1__changePinTest->yourSerialNumber.c_str();
    tfaddress transactionFileAddress;

    int returnValue = 0;
    returnValue = Account::changePassword(toteGateway, myGdi,accountID, accountPin,
                                          newPassword, yourSerialNumber, &transactionFileAddress);

    ns1__changePinTestResponse* result= soap_new_ns1__ChangePinResponse(this);

    result->code = returnValue;
    if (returnValue == ESUCCESS) {
      result->message = &SUCCESS;
      result->transactionFileAddress = transactionFileAddress;
    } else {
      result->message =  &ERROR;
    }

    ns1__changePinTestResponse->changePinTestReturn= result;
    return SOAP_OK;
}
```

Comment: What line causes the error?

Comment: @VictorPolevoy Edited with line

Comment: Do you have only this one single error?

Comment: You forgot the prefix underscore. The struct is _ns1__changePinTestResponse. I suggest using more legible data type names and declarations thereof.

Comment: A leading underscore in `ns1__changePinTestResponse` is missing.

Comment: Looks like you are yet another victim of the incredibly obvious c++ error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the first underscore.  It should be:

```
_ns1__changePinTestResponse
```

not

```
ns1__changePinTestResponse
```